# I need to add comma at the end of first 3 words in the text file using shell script

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell, scripting

I need to add comma at the end of first 3 words in the text file using shell script.

ex : file.txt

```
jan Feb Mar  Chennai India
jan Feb Mar  Hyderabad India
jan Feb Mar  Bangalore India
```

Expected output is :

```
jan,Feb,Mar,  Chennai India
jan,Feb,Mar,  Hyderabad India
jan,Feb,Mar,  Bangalore India
```

Comment: Do you also need to _remove_ the space after the first two words, but not the third?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this job.

sed can do the work:

```
$ cat <your-file> | sed -r 's/(\w+)\s(\w+)\s(\w+)(.*)$/\1, \2, \3,\4/'
```

read can do the work too:

```
$ while read c1 c2 c3 rest; do echo $c1, $c2, $c3, $rest; done < <your-file>
```

awk can also do the work:

```
$ cat <your-file> | awk '{ printf "%s, %s, %s, ", $1, $2, $3; for (i = 4; i <= NF; i++) { printf "%s ", $i; } print ""}'
```

Comment: I prefer to the 'read'. It is simple and robust.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F'  ' '{ gsub(" ", ",", $1); $1 = $1 "," } 1' OFS='  ' file.txt
jan,Feb,Mar,  Chennai India
jan,Feb,Mar,  Hyderabad India
jan,Feb,Mar,  Bangalore India
```

This uses the fact that the input may be interpreted as two double-space-delimited columns. It replaces the spaces in the first column by commas, and adds a comma after it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Also try this:

`awk '{print $1","$2","$3", " substr($0, index($0,$4))}' file.txt`

Output:

```
jan,Feb,Mar, Chennai India
jan,Feb,Mar, Hyderabad India
jan,Feb,Mar, Bangalore India
```

Answer (score 0):

`sed` is a simpler way to do this.`sed` offers an extension that will change the k-th occurrence and all after that.

So, just replace all spaces with comma and replace comma with space after 4th occurrence.

example:

```
 sed -i -e "s/ /,/g" -e 's/,/ /4g' file.txt
```

Output :

```
jan,Feb,Mar, Chennai India
jan,Feb,Mar, Hyderabad India
jan,Feb,Mar, Bangalore India
```